# My app is not running on the emulator - why?

Tags: android, android-emulator

My emulator is running fine and my app got build fine, but my app is not showing on the emulator, and it doesn't gives any error, it just have a long loading saying 
**waiting for target device to come online** and then nothing happens.

Comment: did you check `Logcat` or  `run` for errors.

Comment: Once you have connected the device, go to develoer settings and disble and enable debug mode. It helped me few times once I was having the similar issue.

Comment: @Hari N Jha but it make me to do this everytime, isn't there a way to save it.

Comment: I am not sure, may be mobile specific issue based on updated version.

Answer (score 0):

You can wipe the data on your emulator or delete this emulator and create new one. Sometimes it fix many bugs. If this does not help, then try updating the emulator via Settings -> System Settings -> Android SDK -> SDK tools

Comment: Only wipe up the data in the emulator and the run the emulator again. This thing solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, after having clicked on one of the 2 orientation buttons on the emulator header (portrait/landscape) the emulator did'nt start again, even after closing studio.

I have 2 AVDs, one of them was still working.

I'm not sure, but after having killed the emulator and qemu processes, with the task manager, while studio was running, it started again. But in the meantime, I had restarted Studio at least 2 or 3 times.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34995007)